# MYSQL REPLACE string content with field value

Tags: mysql, select, replace

How can I REPLACE a string value with a other field content?

```
SELECT REPLACE(html_input,'!value',field_value) FROM table
```

Value of html_input is <input type='text' value='!value'>

Value of field_value is test

Expected result:

```
<input type='text' value='test'>
```

Comment: Please tag you MySQL version.

Comment: For any version

Comment: It does not matter is any parameter a literal or a field name.

Comment: Using a field does not work, returns a null field.

Comment: I located the problem. My field is null value, so it returns null.

Comment: The correct is:
SELECT REPLACE(html_input,'!value',IF(field_value IS NULL,'',fieldvalue)) FROM table

Comment: Do not use IF() - there is `COALESCE(field_value, '')`.

Comment: Tks, perfect =o)

Answer (score 1):

String literals must be enclosed by quotes `'`.

Quote symbols within a literal must be quoted by slash as `\'`.

```
SELECT REPLACE(html_input,'!value',field_value) 
FROM table
/* WHERE html_input = '<input type=\'text\' value=\'!value\'>'
     AND field_value = 'test';
*/
```

Comment: I had chosen words that confused the question and it was edited in the wrong way causing confusion.
I reworded the question! Thank you

Comment: @user2175345 Your edition makes WHERE clause unnesessary. I'll comment it... Done.

Comment: This is not a query with WHERE.
Is a replace in a string by a value of a field.
See again